# Error con FPDF en host Gator

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, hosting, fpdf

He intentado subir un formulario a host gator, me carga mi formulario, pero al momento de enviar datos si me los guarda en la base de datos, sin embargo necesito que también los convierta en PDF, uso la librería FPDF

Al momento de dar clic a mi boto enviar y me sale el siguiente error, si alguien me pudiera ayudar por favor ya que nunca había subido un formulario y realmente no sé si se tenga que cambiar o añadir algo

> FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at /home2/certifi5/public_html/certificados/certificados-bvglobal/conexion.php:6)}

Mi base de datos tiene acotejamiento `utf8_unicode_ci`

Conexión *.php*:

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost";
$db_usuario="certifi5_user";
$db_password="beELUFn&B-B7";
$db_nombre="certifi5_bvglobal_certificados";
?>
```

Mi archivo donde se encuentra el pdf:

```
<?php
/* Es preferible usar "require" para que falle en caso de no encontrarse */

require 'conexion.php';
require('fpdf.php');
//require('index.html');

//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');

/*Conexión a la Base de Datos*/
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_password, $db_nombre);

$resultado = $conn->query("
    INSERT INTO datos_usuarios (
        folio_usuario,
        nombre,
        apellido,
        curp,
        curso,
        horas,
        email,
        fecha
    ) VALUES (
        '$folio_usuario',
        '$nombre',
        '$apellido',
        '$curp',
        '$curso',
        '$horas',
        '$email',
        '$fecha'
    )");

if ($resultado) {
$pdf = new FPDF('L', 'mm', 'A4');
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Image('img/constancia.png', 0, 0, 297, 210, 'PNG');

    //NOMBRE Y APELLIDO
    $pdf->SetFont('times', 'B', 34);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(59, 144, 155);
    $nombre_completo = $nombre . " " . $apellido;
    $pdf->Cell(120, 12, '', 0, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(120, 12, '', 0, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(120, 12, '', 0, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(120, 12, '', 0, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(120, 12, '', 0, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(120, 5, '', 0, 1, 'C');
    //$pdf->Cell(0, 0, $nombre_completo, 0, 1, 'C');
    $pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, utf8_decode($nombre_completo), 0, 'C');
$pdf->Output();

    //header('location:nuevo.html');
} else {
    echo "No se inserto";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente, tu archivo `conexion.php` está enviando contenido al navegador, ya sea un espacio o salto de línea y PHP automáticamente genera encabezados para que el navegador "sepa" que va a recibir texto plano o HTML, por lo que no se puede enviar el PDF.

### Algunas recomendaciones:

1. Asegúrate de no enviar salida al navegador hasta que sea necesario, un espacio, un salto de línea, texto, etc. serán los causantes de este tipo de errores.
2. La etiqueta de apertura `<?php` siempre debe estar en la primera línea y primera columna de cada archivo
3. No cierres y abras etiquetas a menos que sea necesario, con esto `?>     <?php` automáticamente se inicia la salida al navegador
4. Nunca uses la etiqueta de cierre `?>` al final de tus scripts, no va a generar error porque no es necesaria
5. En lugar de la etiqueta de cierre `?>` al final de los scripts coloca un comentario, es una buena referencia para saber que el archivo no está incompleto

```
<?php // Esta línea debe estar en la primera fila y primera columna
$db_host="localhost";
$db_usuario="certifi5_user";
$db_password="beELUFn&B-B7";
$db_nombre="certifi5_bvglobal_certificados";

// Fin de archivo
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, si eran las etiquetas de cierre las que provocaron conflicto