# Descarga de archivos del servidor

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, descarga

Necesito descargar unos archivos que están en un servidor con php7.4.
Para ello hice la siguiente petición ajax con XMLHttpRequest:

```
$("#descarga").click(function(){
        console.log(fila);
        if(fila!=""){
            let app=window.location.href.substring(0,window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/"));
            console.log(app);
            let pathservicehost=app+"/AdministracionRespaldoDescargaBD?accion=bajar&archivo="+fila["Respaldo"];
            //la petición ajax es con XMLHttpRequest sin jquery, porque jquery no soporta los blob
            let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            console.log(pathservicehost);
            request.open("GET",pathservicehost, true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",fila["ContentType"]);
            request.responseType = "blob";
            request.onload = function(ex){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsBinaryString(request.response);
                reader.onload = function(e){
                    var isProblema=true;
                    console.log(request.response);
                    try{
                        var jsonObj=JSON.parse(this.result);
                        console.log(jsonObj);
                        if(jsonObj.hasOwnProperty("error")){
                            console.log("Hay error.");
                        }
                    }catch(error){
                        console.log("Es un archivo. No hay error.");
                        isProblema=false;
                    }
                    console.log(isProblema);
                    //console.log(request.response);
                    console.log(request.status);
                    if(!isProblema){
                        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                            var blob = request.response;
                            if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,fila["Respaldo"]);
                            }else{
                                var downloadLink = window.document.createElement("a");
                                var contentTypeHeader = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                                downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob], { type: contentTypeHeader }));
                                downloadLink.download = fila["Respaldo"];
                                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                                downloadLink.click();
                                document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
                            }
                        }else{
                            alert("No se a podido descargar el Archivo del Servidor.");
                        }
                    }else{
                        alert("No se a podido descargar el Archivo del Servidor");
                    }
                };
            };
            request.send();
        }//fin if fila 
    });
```

Y este es el archivo php que invoco:

```
class AdministracionRespaldoDescargaBD extends Controlador{
    
function mostrar(){}
function descarga(){
error_log(print_r($_GET,true));
if ($_GET['accion'] == "bajar") {
    // Comprobamos que la direccion de donde se a pedido la petición sea del servidor (no funciona con FileReference de flash e Internet Explorer 7)
    /*if (!strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
        exit();
    }*/
    
    // Iniciamos las variables de sesion
    session_start();
    
    // Comprobamos que la variable de sesion 'usuario' se alla establecido
    if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        exit;
    }
    
    $servidor=$_SESSION['servidor'];
    $usuario=$_SESSION['nomusuario'];
    $pass=$_SESSION['pass'];
    $puerto=$_SESSION['puerto'];
    $bd=$_SESSION['nombd'];
    $Usuario=$_SESSION['usuario'];
    
    // Creamos la conexión a la base de datos
    $conn = new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$pass,$bd,$puerto);   
        $conn->set_charset("utf8");
    // Si fallo la conexion nos salimos
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        exit;
    }
    
    // Realizamos la consulta para saber si el usuario esta conectado y tiene derecho a administrar
    $Consulta = "Select If ((u.Sesion = 1) And (p.AdminSist = 1), true, false) as 'Puede' From siau.usuarios u, siau.permisos p Where u.Usuario = '".$conn->escape_string($Usuario)."' And p.Usuario = '".$conn->escape_string($Usuario)."';";
    $Resultado = $conn->query($Consulta);
    $Fila = mysqli_fetch_array($Resultado);
    
    // Si no esta conectado o no tiene derecho a administrar nos salimos
    if (!$Fila['Puede']) {
        exit;
    }
    $dir="";
    if(strpos(php_uname(),"Windows") !== false){
        $dir="C:/Respaldos/";
    }else{//Linux
        $dir="/Respaldos/";
    }
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($gd = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($archivo = readdir($gd)) !== false) {
                if ($archivo==$_GET['archivo']){
                    $maxtamarc = filesize($dir.$archivo);
                    $acttamarc = 0;
                    $maxtamlec = 41943040; // 40 Mb
                    //$maxtamlec = 10485760; // 10 Mb
                    $contentType=mime_content_type($dir.$archivo);
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$archivo.'"');
                    header('Content-type: '.$contentType);
                    //header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
                    header('Content-Length: '.$maxtamarc);
                    header('Pragma: public');
                    error_log($dir.$archivo);
                    error_log($contentType);
                    $fp = fopen($dir.$archivo,"rb");
                    $contenido = fread($fp, filesize($dir.$archivo));

                        /*
                        while ($acttamarc < $maxtamarc) {
                            if ($contenido = fread($fp, $maxtamlec)) {
                                $acttamarc += $maxtamlec;
                                echo $contenido;
                            } else {
                                exit();
                            }
                        }*/
                    fclose($fp);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($gd);
    }
}


}

}

$x =new AdministracionRespaldoDescargaBD;
$x->descarga();
    
?>
```

Todo parece funcionar correctamente, el navegador hace la descarga, hasta que abro el archivo y me dice: **El archivo tiene un formato desconocido o esta dañado**.
El archivo es un respaldo de mysql `.sql.gz` creado en ubuntu, aunque yo estoy desarrollando en windows, para ello baje la carpeta y la puse en `C:/Respaldos/`.
Creo que puede ser la codificación pero no se como arreglar esto. Espero me puedan ayudar.

**ACTUALIZACION:**

He descubierto algo: los archivos que descargo traen un espacio al inicio.
Arriba en la imagen esta el archivo original empieza con el hexadecimal 1F.
Abajo en la imagen esta el archivo dañado y empieza con un 20 hexadecimal que es un espacio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No se de donde aparece eso ni como quitárselo,pero si lo quito manualmente y guardo el archivo ya abre, ayuda.

Comment: ¿Tienes un programa adecuado para abrir archivos `.gz` en tu equipo?

Comment: Si, en `C:/Respaldos/` tengo los que copie de `ubuntu` y abren bien con `winrar`. De hecho la línea que imprimo justo antes de abrir el archivo en php `error_log($dir.$archivo);`, si copio la ruta que imprime esa línea y la pego en el explorer de `windows` abre el archivo con `winrar` perfectamente, pero si es la versión que descargo, el tamaño de archivo es el mismo que el original pero sigue saliendo ese mensaje, y ya probé abrirlos con `winzip` y `7zip` pero ocurre lo mismo, los 3 programas abren el original pero no el descargado.

Comment: Yo verificaría dos cosas: 1. ¿Ese archivo en sí no está dañado realmente? ¿Abriría por ejemplo desde la consola del servidor? 2. Dado que usas código dinámico en el cliente, verifica que estás indicando todos los parámetros adecuados (mime type) y demás. 3. Se podría también probar con un archivo de la misma extensión más pequeño, asegurándote de que dicho archivo no está corrompido.

Comment: Para evitar ese espacio, revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/385692/error-con-fpdf-en-host-gator/385694#385694)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya quedo, resulta que cuando se escribe a disco php usa un buffer de salida. Solo tuve que limpiar dicho buffer para que no tenga "valores silvestres de memoria" (basura), por eso aparecía ese espacio. Ese buffer lo limpie con la instrucción `ob_clean()`:

```
if ($archivo==$_GET["archivo"]){
                    $maxtamarc = filesize($dir.$archivo);
                    $acttamarc = 0;
                    $maxtamlec = 41943040; // 40 Mb
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$archivo.'"');
                    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
                    header('Content-Length: '.$maxtamarc);
                    header('Pragma: public');
                        
                    $fp = fopen($dir.$archivo, 'r');
                        while ($acttamarc < $maxtamarc) {
                            if ($Contenido = fread($fp, $maxtamlec)) {
                                $acttamarc += $maxtamlec;
                                ob_clean();
                                echo $Contenido;
                            } else {
                                exit();
                            }
                        }
                    fclose($fp);
                }
```

De todos modos gracias por la ayuda, sus respuestas me dieron pistas para encontrar la solución después de 3 días que llevaba con esto.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar con `fetch` que, de hecho, tiene una opción para [descargar archivos BLOB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob#Example).

Solo una observación: El encabezado `Content-Type` corresponde al tipo de datos que estás enviando en la petición, no a lo que esperas recibir y, probablemente, sería conveniente eliminar las opciones, dejando solo `fetch(pathservicehost)`, ya que el método por defecto es *GET* y los encabezados tampoco son necesarios en este caso según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch).

```
$("#descarga").click(function(){
    console.log(fila);
    if(fila!=""){
        let app=window.location.href.substring(0,window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/"));
        console.log(app);
        let pathservicehost=app+"/AdministracionRespaldoDescargaBD?accion=bajar&archivo="+fila["Respaldo"];
        fetch(pathservicehost, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': fila['ContentType']
            }
        }).then(response => {
            // Si la petición tuvo éxito, response.ok es verdadero
            if(response.ok) {
                // Devolver la respuesta como BLOB
                return response.blob();
            }
            throw 'El archivo no pudo ser descargado como BLOB ' + response.statusText;
        }).then(result => {
            let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            // Result es un BLOB, no necesitas modificarlo
            downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(result);
            downloadLink.download = fila["Respaldo"];
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        }).catch(e => console.log('Error descargando archivo: ' + e);

    }
});
```

En cuanto a PHP, no es necesario abrir el directorio y recorrer el contenido para buscar el archivo, basta con la función [`file_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists) y, si acaso, verificar que no se trata de un directorio.

Asegúrate de enviar el encabezado correcto para tamaño de archivo, usando ['filesize()'](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filesize) y, finalmente, te recomiendo usar [`readFile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.readfile.php), que lee el archivo y lo envía al navegador sin tener que ejecutar instrucciones adicionales:

```
$archivo = $dir . $file;
if(file_exists($archivo) && !is_dir($archivo)) {
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
    header('Content-type: ' . mime_content_type($archivo));
    // Especifica el tamaño exacto del archivo
    header('Content-Length: '. filesize($archivo));
    header('Pragma: public');
    error_log($archivo);
    error_log($contentType);
    // Leer archivo y enviarlo directamente a la salida (navegador)
    readfile($archivo);
}
```

**Nota:** Por seguridad, deberías verificar que el nombre de archivo no tenga diagonales `/` para evitar que un usuario malintencionado pueda descargar cualquier cosa de tu sitio.